# Home indicator for iPhone X changes color after re-entering foreground after initial launch

Tags: ios, swift

With multiple apps I have created, the first time I launch the app the home indicator on iPhone X devices will be a certain color. If I, for example, move a different app to the foreground and then come back to my app, the home indicator will change to a different, and what I believe is the "correct," color, even though the background hasn't changed. Below I give an example of such an occurrence in one of my apps.

This is the background color:

```
static let yellow = UIColor(red: 252.0 / 255.0, green: 184.0 / 255.0, blue: 20.0 / 255.0, alpha: 1.0)
```

After initial launch:

[image]

After re-entering the foreground:

[image]

I am aware that as developers we have no control over the color of the home indicator, I'm just wondering if anyone else has dealt with the same problem. Perhaps there is some way to make it consistent? I just don't like inconsistency.

Comment: I wrote an in-depth article about the home indicator color if you want to learn more about its behavior:  https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/reverse-engineering-the-iphone-x-home-indicator-color-a4c112f84d34/

Comment: @TanjimaKothiya Wow, that explains a lot. That's very interesting. It seems like there isn't necessarily a solution to this problem then...